# Button Stops Functioning when Trying to Assign Session Variable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session-variables

I am trying to retain a list of strings after a button press and have been using session variables. This is a snippet of the code:

**.aspx page**

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlAdd" >
     <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlOrder" >
          <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Select an Order Type</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Value="1">hey there</asp:ListItem>
     </asp:DropDownList>
     <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlOrderStatus" >
          <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Select an Order Status</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Value="1">another option</asp:ListItem>
     </asp:DropDownList>
</asp:Panel>
<br />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAdd" Text="Add" />
```

**.vb page**

```
Protected Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        Dim list As New List(Of String)

        list = Session("flist")
        list.Add(ddlOrder.SelectedItem.Text + " " + ddlOrderStatus.SelectedItem.Text)
        Session("flist") = list

        For i As Integer = 0 To 10
            MsgBox(i.ToString + "  " + list(i))
        Next

        MsgBox("Here")
 End Sub
```

At the point that I assign the `Session` variable to `list` with `list = Session("flist")`, nothing will happen on the button click. If I remove that line, the rest of the button fires. Am I using the `Session` variable incorrectly? How can I achieve this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list (of String) cannot be nothing before you are going to add elements into this list, So, change your code as follows:

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

    Dim list As New List(Of String)
    Dim objList As Object = Session.Item("flist")

    If objList IsNot Nothing AndAlso TypeOf (objList) Is List(Of String) Then
        list = CType(objList, List(Of String))
    End If

    list.Add(ddlOrder.SelectedItem.Text + " " + ddlOrderStatus.SelectedItem.Text)
    Session("flist") = list

    For i As Integer = 0 To list.Count - 1
        MsgBox(i.ToString + "  " + list(i))
    Next

    MsgBox("Here on end")

End Sub
```